# String.match() with indeterminate characters after the regex

Tags: javascript, regex

If I Have a String in Javascript like this:

```
var html = '"<div class="info" id="infobox">Average Speed: 83kph<br/><br/>Max Speed: 95kph<br/><br/>Event Started At: 42.929126, -78.834093<br/><br/>Event Last Recorded At: 42.920754, -78.843596<br/><br/>Event Duration: 0H, 0M, 56S <br/><br/>";
```

And I want to store all the substrings after ': ', how would I do that using the `match()` method? I think I want something where the regex is ': %indeterminateAmountofCharacters<'.

I want the colon / blankspace to be the start, then the '<' to be the indicator for the end, and I want to save everything in between as an element in the array that `match()` would return.

`Ie. ['83kph', '95kph', '42.929126, -78.834093', '0H, 0M, 56S ']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a global "search and don't replace."  You have to do the sub-group capturing semi-manually, though.

```
var matches = [];
html.replace(/: (.*?)</g, function () {
    matches.push(arguments[1]);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kh35R/

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a pattern like this:

```
/: (.*?)</
```

This will match a `:` character, followed by space, followed by zero or more of any character, non-greedily, captured in group 1, followed by a `<` character.

Unfortunately, calling `.match` with this will just return the first match:

```
html.match(/: (.*?)</) // [": 83kph<", "83kph"]
```

And adding the global flag (`g`) will give you all matches, but not separated out by group:

```
html.match(/: (.*?)</g) 
// [": 83kph<", ": 95kph<", ": 42.929126, -78.834093<", ": 42.920754, -78.843596<", ": 0H, 0M, 56S <"]
```

One solution is use [`.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) instead, and then [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out every other element, like this:

```
html.split(/: (.*?)</).filter(function(x, i) { return i % 2 ; });
// ["83kph", "95kph", "42.929126, -78.834093", "42.920754, -78.843596", "0H, 0M, 56S "]
```

Or use a [`.exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) in a loop:

```
var re = /: (.*?)</g,
    results = [],
    match;
while (match = re.exec(html)) {
    results.push(match[1]);
}
console.log(results);
// ["83kph", "95kph", "42.929126, -78.834093", "42.920754, -78.843596", "0H, 0M, 56S "]
```

Answer (score 0):

edit: p.s.w.g beat me.

This should work:

```
:\s(.*?)<
```

[See it in action.](http://regex101.com/r/lM4mD2)